# What kind of serial encoding is this?

Tags: serial, reverse-engineering, encoding, manchester-coding

I'm involved in some reverse engineering of a device I need to interface with.  With what little I know, and being able to capture a single data transmission, I think I've narrowed down the encoding method.  I suspect it might be a custom or obscure method because I can't find anything that matches what appears to be happening here.

At first I thought it might be a form of Manchester/Bi-Phase encoding, but any examples I've seen show transitions both rising and falling.  I have only falling transitions, and transitions between bits can be rising or falling.

Here's how the bit stream begins:

[image]

I have to assume that there are either some start or stop bits (maybe both) because the number of data bits I expect doesn't match how many bit frames I see overall.  The difference is in the low single digits and number of expected bits is in the high double digits.  I don't think the number is relevant to this discussion.  I only mention this because it corroborates my framing of the bits.

Somewhere in the middle of the stream I snipped this section to show where I'm marking each bit frame and what's happening along the way (scale is same as above):

[image]

I've marked an arrow on each transition I believe to be the start of a bit frame.  I suspect that no transition mid-frame is one logic level and a falling transition is the other level.  Though I've marked up the image with 1's and 0's, it could just as easily be inverted.

Has anyone seen this type of serial encoding before?  Does it have a name?  How likely is it I'm making a mistake with my interpretation?

EDIT 1: I can probably figure this part out, but if you've successfully decoded something like this in software (low level firmware) I'm interested in hearing about your solution.

EDIT 2: The repeating bit pattern in the marked-up image is coincidental.  Below is another section of the bit stream to illustrate this more clearly.  I would post the entire thing, but for technical reasons I can't do that right now.

[image]

Comment: So.... is there a clock or just this one signal?

Comment: Looks like there are three cases. 100% high time, about 33% high time and 0% high time. So maybe it is a three-level pulse-width modulation scheme with constant symbol rate of one symbol per period. I don't see how you can reverse engineer it without capturing a stream of known value. At least not easily.

Comment: @mkeith No additional clock.  This is it.

Comment: @Sparky961 You can see the self-clocking in the diagram you show.

Comment: @jonk That's what I had thought too.  I'm not too concerned about the "extra" transition mid-frame in terms of decoding it.  I just want some reassurance that I'm looking at this the right way.

Comment: @Sparky961 Just pick out the obvious self-clocking and then it's obvious which is a 0 and which is a 1.

Comment: @Sparky961 See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPv7Z.png). Pretty obvious, eh?

Comment: you may  be decoding "11" where the symbol is actually "1"  not all line protocols have constant bit rate.

Comment: @jonk I've added another section of the bit stream showing that the "clocking" you're picking out of it isn't repetitive.  Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're indicating in the image you linked.

Comment: @Jasen Fair comment, but when I overlay the same time period for each bit I get very close to the number of bits I expect.  I'd get a very odd number otherwise, and would be able to make even less sense of the data.

Comment: see if you can find a odd number of your 1s

Comment: How many bits do you expect? why? how long is the code? howe many 1s? , how many 0s?

Comment: @Jasen I'm not seeing how that's a useful direction to go here.

Comment: yet I am not seeing how it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing what looks like a variable rate code where a 1 is a long pulse and a long rest and a 0 is a short pulse and a short-ish rest.

[image]

Comment: I might be willing to consider this if you explained your reasoning.  Otherwise your answer makes me think you didn't read the question.

Comment: Ok, I see where you're going with this now.  Let me see if decoding it like this would make any sense.

Comment: The idea is appealing, and there's definitely a logical symmetry to it.  But if I decode it using this technique then I only get 70% of the number of bits I expect to be there.  I'm not prepared to accept or reject the idea until I can do some more testing with different data.  Is there perhaps a name for this encoding technique so that I could look into it further?

Comment: I'm not aware of any name,  it like morse and like one-wire  but isn't an exact match for either.

Comment: Although this doesn't completely answer my question, it has pointed me in a direction I wouldn't have otherwise gone and thus has helped greatly.  I think what I might be looking at, and what I'm going to try decoding more with is something similar to J1850 PWM, or less likely VPWM.  Here's a page with lots of pictures but is short on description: https://www.cnblogs.com/shangdawei/p/4769620.html